# Seen from above

Tags: visual, rebus, progressive-matrix

**I'm looking for an image that represents this puzzle. Can you tell me what that image is?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the image might be this:

> [image: The Pentagon, VA, seen from above]

The matrix:

> The shapes in the rightmost column can be obtained by (a) removing the points indicated in the second column from the original polygon in the left column and (b) reflecting the resulting shape along the line indicated in the third columns. The result is:
>
>  [image: completed matrix with a pentagon in the bottom right cell]

The rebus:

> After replacing the red square in the clue at the bottom with the new shape, we get:
>
>  [image: "Pentagon in the U.S."]
>
>  which might mean "[The Pentagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pentagon) in the U.S.".

Comment: You got it! That's the image, well done!